# How to implement soft assertions in Cypress and stop execution on failure?

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am working on test automation using Cypress, and I want to implement soft assertions so that the execution doesn't stop when one step fails. I have already tried using the `cypress-soft-assertions` package, but I'm encountering an error.

Here's the specific problem:

1. I installed the `cypress-soft-assertions` package with `npm i -D cypress-soft-assertions`.
2. In my test code, I have a method `validateElementVisibility` where I want to perform a soft assertion on element visibility:

   ```js
   validateElementVisibility(element, logMsg) {
       this.logger.log(logMsg);
       element.beter('be.visible'); // There's a typo here: it should be 'better' instead of 'beter'.
   }
   ```

   However, when I run this code, I get the following error:

   ```
   cy.ensureAttached is not a function
   node_modules/cypress-soft-assertions/src/index.js:229:1
   ```
3. To handle exceptions and prevent the test from stopping, I've also added some exception handling code in my Cypress configuration:

   ```js
   Cypress.on("fail", (err, runnable) => {
       console.log(err.message);
       return false;
   });

   Cypress.on("uncaught:exception", (e, runnable) => {
       console.log("error", e);
       console.log("runnable", runnable);
       console.log("error", e.message);
       return false;
   });

   Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
       if (err.message.includes("chai")) {
           cy.log(`Chai Assertion Error: ${err.message}`);
           return false;
       } else {
           throw err;
       }
   });
   ```

   Despite all these measures, the test execution still doesn't stop on assertion failures.

Here's a snippet of my base page code for reference:

```js
import TestReportLogger from "../../../support/TestReportLogger"

class BasePage {
    constructor() {
        this.logger = a TestReportLogger();
    }

    // ... other methods ...

    validateElementVisibility(element, logMsg) {
        this.logger.log(logMsg);
        element.should('be.visible')
    }

    // other methods 
}

export default BasePage;
```

Answer (score 3):

Most of those examples are outside of the scope of soft assertions.

- *`element.beter('be.visible')`; // There's a typo here*  - This is a syntax error not a soft assertion
- *`Cypress.on("fail"`* - This stops the test from ever failing regardless of assertion type, but does not continue beyond the fail point. It certainly does ***stop execution on failure*** but if you want soft assertions you want to ***continue execution on failure***.
- `Cypress.on("uncaught:exception"` - This is for app errors that are outside of the  intentions of the test, i.e test code does not handle.
- `cypress-soft-assertions` - This is only for Cypress versions below 12, has not been updated for query commands.

To handle your specific example of the visibility using a soft assertion, do something like this:

```js
validateElementVisibility(element, logMsg) {
  this.logger.log(logMsg);
  element.then($el => {
    const isVisible = $el.is(':visible')
    Cypress.log({
      displayName: 'isVisible',
      message: `${element.selector} isVisible: ${isVisible}`
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for that but I am getting TypeError that
element.is is not a function

Comment: element is like cy.get("css selector")

Comment: I adjusted the code to suit your usage.

Comment: Thank you very much after adding this Cypress.$(element).is(':visible'). The code is working now, but when the test fails, it's hard to distinguish because it shows as text. Is there any way that it shows visually as well?

Comment: You can add property `state: 'failed'` to the `Cypress.log()` to give the line red text (but only affects the log not the test failure).

Comment: Sorry, the code is not working correctly for every situation. It is giving me el.is(), which is not a function. I am using Npx Cypress Open.
Could you please help me?

Comment: Sorry, there is too little information to go on. For further help I need details or clarity on what situation is working and not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255192/discussion-between-user16561758-and-aladin-spaz).